# How to remove unsubscribe link in Gmail for emails sent from Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

We're including our own subscribe/unsubscribe link to the emails but users can still see this link and can unsubscribe from the all subscribers list. We also noticed that this is showing in gmail only. How can we hide this?

[image]

Comment: Figured that we can hide this by selecting 'transactional' as the send classification and then insert the unsubscribe link in our emails. However, technically, we are sending commercial emails. Do we have any other option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some Email Service Providers (including Gmail-Web and iOS Mail) take the "List-Unsubscribe" data from the email to create an easy way for their customers to unsubscribe from potentially unsolicited emails.

You can view this code in Gmail by doing the following:
Click the drop down to see the email options:
[image]

Search for "Unsubscribe" in the text:
[image]

Unfortunately, there is **no way to disable this function**, and removing the List-Unsubscribe data from your message data would likely trigger a few spam/junk flags.
Good marketing practice is to give your subscribers an easy way to remove themselves from your list. After all, you don't want to be sending emails to customers who don't want to receive them!

Comment: Hi @cameronrobert, I agree and we are providing them a custom unsubscribe link within the email body to make sure they receive the correct emails. However, the unsubscribe link that gmail provides is the standard one that unsubscribes them from the all subs list. One option that we have is to use transactional send classification - but its not best practice. Hoping that there would be another way to resolve this.

Comment: We have the same issue with our email marketing communications. We've found that by making the unsubscribe link more prevalent, customers were less likely to complain or take "extraordinary steps" to remove themselves from lists - such as flagging emails as SPAM.

Comment: Have you engaged Salesforce support? This sounds like a perfect idea for future development, to allow us to select how one is to opt-out (i.e. replacing the all sub element, with a publication list or something else)